# An error when build Boost Asio 1.55 for Android

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I had read tutorial for build Boost for Android with link : https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android . So i had a problems that i can't fix .

> "Building boost version: 1.55.0
>   Cleaning: boost_1_55_0
>   Detected Android NDK version 10d (64-bit)
>   ./build-android.sh: line 255: patch: command not found
>   ERROR: Patch failure !! Please check your patches directory!
>          Try to perform a clean build using --clean .
>          Problem patch: /cygdrive/d/BTS/BoostLib/boost_1_55_build_android/p                    atches/boost-1_55_0/boost-1_55_0.patch"

My NDK use r10d ( 32 64 bit).  Anyone can help me fix that problem? Thanks you a lots !  :)

Comment: `patch: command not found` so install it.

Comment: Can you explain more . What i need install? Thanks! @TimofeyStolbov